# SuperUser TOS and site content for informative talks

Tags: discussion, policy, legality

[The Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) has two clauses about site content. The first expressly prohibits any and all use of site content. And, the second states portions of site content are made available as archives and licensed under a derivation of creative commons.

Does Super User have a specific policy regarding the use of content provided in lectures or talks on subjects which the Stack Exchange covers?

I'm fishing for ideas to use for a local computer users group at my local public library. The public library has strict policies for non-profit events or meetings. Any use at said meeting would thus be covered under this use policy. Certainly attribution and sources would be clearly disclosed. I am not looking for loopholes to snaffle Super User content, only looking for useful tips as discussion material for meeting activities. Think [BayChi](http://www.baychi.org/bof/) (though this is not in any way connected with ACM).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first clause says:

> The Network and its contents are intended solely for the use of the
>   Network Subscribers and may only be used in accordance with the terms
>   of this Agreement

Note that there is a distinction between *Network Content* (the web site, its design, trademarks, text and graphics) and *Subscriber Content* (content provided by the users).

The second clause says:

> You agree that all *Subscriber Content* that You contribute to the
>   Network will be licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution Share
>   Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the right and license to use,
>   copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative
>   works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so
>   (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services

In short, you may copy and make derivative works from the *Subscriber Content* without permission, so long as you provide attribution (credit to the original author(s)) and license your derived work under cc:wiki.

The same is not true of the *Network Content.*  The Network Content is protected by copyright in much the same way as other websites; you must obtain permission from Stack Exchange to use the Network Content for other purposes.

Comment: Ooooh! I thought "Network Content" was some kind of umbrella term for all content of the network of sites. And, I missed the "and allow others to do so...", and interpreted it much more restrictively. thanks